# Closed form of $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}\dfrac{f(x)}{\ln(cx)}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives

Is there some closed formula (except [general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)) to evaluate these derivatives?

1. $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}\dfrac{e^{ax}}{\ln(cx)}$
2. $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}\dfrac{\sin(ax)}{\ln(cx)}$
3. $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}\dfrac{\cos(ax)}{\ln(cx)}$

or in general $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}\dfrac{f(x)}{\ln(cx)}$

I tried to calculate them but I'm not able to see a repeating pattern.

Comment: For $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\ln^{-1}(cx)$, use [this Stirling number formula](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Log/20/02/0004/). In the “ratios” section of [differentiation identities](https://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralIdentities/9/), you will find a double sum for $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$.